# JQuery's slide effect

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I playing with this code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>slide demo</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <style>
            #toggle {
                width: 100px;
                height: 100px;
                background: #ccc;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Click anywhere to toggle the box.</p>
        <div id="toggle"></div>
        <script>
            $(document).click(function() {
                $("#toggle").toggle("slide");
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

which is found here: `http://api.jqueryui.com/slide-effect/`
I want to use the effect when the page is loaded, and not by a user click

I have used it on my own page, where I do want a div to slide in on the page,once the page has loaded. So I am doing this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout( function() {
        $("#panel-1027").toggle("slide");
    }, 2000);
});
```

The problem is that instead of sliding in, the div slides out of the page. How can I go about this?

Comment: Set the panel to `display: hidden` by default.

Comment: create some fiddle so that we can try it

Answer (score 1):

hide your `toggle` element by default and add direction to your toggle for particular direction

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout( function() {
        $("#toggle").toggle("slide",{direction: 'up'});
    }, 2000);
});
```